# Gitlab SSL Configuration for both Internal and External Access

Tags: docker, ssl, gitlab

Looking for a little help here. Trying to bootstrap a small side business, and I have never been the DevOps guy. I use the web hosted version Gitlab to store my codebase, but I am unable to use it to act as a repository for docker images that I am creating from that code. The images that I am generating are quite large and exceed the token expiration when I am attempting to push back to the registry from the group gitlab-runner that I have installed on my personal machine. I have an extra machine sitting around, so I installed gitlab-ee and exposed it through a dynamic dns service (NoIP). I then mirrored the repositories that I want to generate images for on my locally hosted gitlab instance. At first, I tried to use a runner that was on the same machine as my gitlab instance, but always failed due to all available memory being consumed and locked up the machine. All in all, gitlab docs pretty much don’t run the runner and instance on the same machine. So, I went back to using the runner I originally used for the web hosted instance, but I am having issues pushing to my local instance. When trying to push to my repository (through the ddns URL), I end up getting a lot of this:

`e4fdbd3bf512: Retrying in X seconds`

And it eventually times out due to job time limit or token time limit. I am guessing this is due to my connectivity not being great. What I would like to do is have the (installed on a local machine) runner push to the local IP on my network, but I am unsure how to do this with the SSL setup. When trying to login and push in my pipeline, I get the following error:

`Error response from daemon: Get "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/v2/": x509: cannot validate certificate for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

How do I correct this without affecting the https:// SSL that is already setup for when accessing the instance from the DDNS? Appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: It sounds like you've actually got several issues here... (1) GitLab [doesn't support using multiple external URLs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21319) and (2) you seem to be having a **docker** TLS issue ("`Error response from daemon`" which is likely separate from your connection issues to GitLab) -- this on top of potential DNS/TLS issues you have with your connection to GitLab.

Comment: You seem to be using an HTTPS URL with an IP address instead of an hostname. While technically it is possible to make it work, it is often far more work than "normal" hostname based HTTPS URLs, so if that is really the case you might want to look at that. Your TLS error is basically because the hostname/IP address in. your URL does not exist in your certificate SAN section. Other than that your question may be a better fit on [sf] than here.

Comment: I need to clarify, I am not attempting to use multiple URLs for Gitlab. My local instance is being exposed through a single DDNS URL. You did however, make something clear to me, I should just be concentrating on the TLS issue with Docker. Like I mentioned my TLS understanding is pretty much nonexistent. I just set up according to the Gitlab Docs. What I am trying to accomplish begin able to access the docker repository externally, but allowing my gitlab-runner to push in my local network without having to go out through the DDNS URL.

Comment: For usual programs you can have the program use the domain name (what you call the DDNS URL) and use /etc/hosts to resolve that domain name to the internal IP address. I don't use gitlab so I can't confirm if it is usual.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned attempts at getting this to work. Ran through a bunch of scenarios of creating my on CA and trying to create certificates for the IP address and share that with the other machine. Ultimately, gitlab obscures some things with LetsEncrypt. Funny enough it was just a connectivity issue where I was getting timeouts. Ended up hard-lining both machines and getting better throughput. Able to push ~6GB docker images up through the URL.